# How to log GRPC request and response in Nestjs?

Tags: node.js, logging, nestjs, grpc

I am trying to log the grpc request and response in my nestjs project. It seems that the middleware would help me do that. However, the middleware in nesjs is for HTTP only. So, is there any other way that can be used to solve my problem? Maybe interceptors?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the examples on this [github](https://github.com/grpc/proposal/blob/master/L5-node-client-interceptors.md#a-simple-example). I used the following code to log the request/response and redact the logs for a gRPC client:

```js
// users.module.ts

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    ClientsModule.registerAsync([
      {
        name: USERS_PACKAGE,
        imports: [ConfigModule],
        useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
          transport: Transport.GRPC,
          options: {
            package: 'users',
            credentials: credentials.createInsecure(),
            protoPath: join(__dirname, './proto/users.proto'),
            url: configService.get<string>('services.users.url'),
            loader: { keepCase: true },
            channelOptions: {
              interceptors: [
                (options, nextCall) => {
                  const logger: Logger = new Logger('UsersModule');

                  const redactedFields: string[] = configService.get<string[]>('logger.redact.fields');
                  const path: string = options.method_definition.path;

                  logger.verbose('-------------------------------------- GRPC CALL ----------------------------------');

                  const interceptingCall = new InterceptingCall(
                    nextCall(options),
                    GrpcLoggingInterceptor(path, redactedFields),
                  );

                  return interceptingCall;
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        }),
        inject: [ConfigService],
      },
    ]),
  ],
  providers: [GetUsersClient],
  exports: [GetUsersClient],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

The grpc logging interceptor to intercept the grpc requests

```js
// grpc-logging.interceptor.ts

import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';

export const GrpcLoggingInterceptor = (path: string, redactedFields: string[]) => {
  const logger: Logger = new Logger('GrpcLoggingInterceptor');

  function redact(data: string): string {
    return JSON.stringify(data, (k, v) => (redactedFields.includes(k) ? `[Redacted]` : v));
  }

  return {
    start: function (metadata, listener, next) {
      const newListener = {
        onReceiveMetadata: function (metadata, next) {
          logger.verbose(`response metadata : ${redact(metadata)}`);
          next(metadata);
        },
        onReceiveMessage: function (message, next) {
          logger.verbose(`response body : ${redact(message)}`);
          next(message);
        },
        onReceiveStatus: function (status, next) {
          logger.verbose(`response status : ${redact(status)}`);
          next(status);
        },
      };
      next(metadata, newListener);
    },

    sendMessage: function (message, next) {
      logger.verbose(`path: ${JSON.stringify(path)}`);
      logger.verbose(`request body : ${redact(message)}`);
      next(message);
    },
  };
};
```

The fields to redact:

```js
// config.yaml

logger:
    redact:
        fields:
            - token
            - password
            - address
            - telephone
```

Comment: A great solution that includes a redaction feature

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [Interceptor](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors#aspect-interception). In fact, that's exactly what my [OgmaInterceptor](https://ogma.jaymcdoniel.dev/docs/nestjs/interceptor) does, and there's [even a plugin for gRPC](https://ogma.jaymcdoniel.dev/docs/nestjs/rpc/grpc). In general, just something simple like

```js
@Injectable()
export class LoggingInterceptor {

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler) {
    const start = Date.now()
    console.log('Request start');
    return next.handle().pipe(
      tap((data) => {
        console.log(`Request took ${Date.now() - start}ms. Response length: ${Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(data) ?? '').length} bytes`);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

would be a simple first pass at writing something for this

Comment: Hi Jay, if I use OgmaInterceptor for grpc logging (for Global), based on my understanding, I need to  add OgmaModule to app.module: @Module(
  OgmaModule.forRoot({
    interceptor: {
      rpc: GrpcParser
  })
)
export class AppModule {}. Then, in main.ts :   const logger = app.get<OgmaService>(OgmaService);
  app.useLogger(logger);   Overall, the solution would be: using middleware for HTTP req/res logging, using Interceptor for grpc req/res logging

Comment: Is this Interceptor that can work with Winston? since I need to send the log to elastic search.

Comment: Currently that interceptor only works with ogma, as that is how I wrote it. You can use ogma to send logs to anywhere you want (via a custom `stream`), but you could use the source code as an inspiration if you'd like

Comment: I have to use the default interceptor from nest since I need to work with Winston. In my interceptor, I do the same here https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors. If I call the rest API(HTTP), it can work as expect. how ever, if I call the grpc function, nothing to the log. Am I missing something?

Comment: If it's a hybrid application (HTTP + RPC) then you need to pass the [`inheritAppConfig`](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/hybrid-application#sharing-configuration) option when connecting the microservice

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! I wonder if "context" includes both the request and response data? It seems that "next" does not contain much data.